# Not Plotting or showing data on the Map

Tags: python, matplotlib, geojson, choropleth

obtainign data from https://infra.datos.gob.ar/catalog/modernizacion/dataset/7/distribution/7.12/download/provincias.geojson

and not being able to plot the map

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import plotly.express as px

df4 = pd.read_excel('provincias.xls')

repo_url = 'https://infra.datos.gob.ar/catalog/modernizacion/dataset/7/distribution/7.12/download/provincias.geojson' #Archivo GeoJSON

ar_regions_geo = requests.get(repo_url).json()

fig = px.choropleth(data_frame=df4, 
                    geojson=ar_regions_geo, 
                    locations='provincia_id',
                    featureidkey='properties.id',  
                    color='Total', 
                    color_continuous_scale="burg", 
               )
fig.update_geos(showcountries=True, showcoastlines=True, showland=True, fitbounds="locations")

fig.show()
```

df4 in the following picture

[image]

Comment: The geometry of the geojson file used to fill the map must be polygonal or multipolygonal. The geojson you are using is point. Can you also provide sample data?

Comment: Thank you very much, can you explain what do you mean by sample data please?? you mean the data frame im using???

Comment: Yes, can you show some example data of what df4 is?

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in my comment, the geojson geometry you have is Point, so you can draw a `px.scatter_geo()` with it. See the reference for a similar [example](https://plotly.com/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/#basic-example-with-geopandas).
I have converted your geojson to geopandas format and added a dummy sequence of numbers. The reason for this is that the id in your sample data and the id in the geojson were not identical. If your data had the same id, this would not be necessary.

I think the original intention was to fill the map with your data, so I get the geojson needed for that from [here](https://cartographyvectors.com/map/1413-argentina-with-regions). I have created a new sample data based on this geojson file as the region id of this data and yours are different. I use this data to apply your code. As a result, it seems that some regions are not displayed. The cause may be in the geojson, but I am able to show the basic structure. All you need to do is find the geojson that matches your data.

**px.scatter_geo():**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd

repo_url = 'https://infra.datos.gob.ar/catalog/modernizacion/dataset/7/distribution/7.12/download/provincias.geojson' #Archivo GeoJSON

ar_regions_geo = requests.get(repo_url).json()
geo_df = gpd.read_file(repo_url)
df5 = geo_df[['id']].copy()
df5['Total'] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(150000, 17000000, len(geo_df)))
geo_df2 = geo_df.merge(df5, on='id')

fig = px.scatter_geo(data_frame=geo_df2,
                     lat=geo_df.geometry.y,
                     lon=geo_df.geometry.x,
                     hover_name="nombre",
                     size=geo_df2['Total'],
                     color=geo_df2['Total']                     
               )
fig.update_geos(showcountries=True,
                showcoastlines=True,
                showland=True,
                fitbounds="locations")

fig.update_layout(autosize=True, height=350, margin={"r":0,"t":20,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open('./argentina-with-regions_1413.geojson', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    ar_regions_geo = json.load(f)

ids, names = [],[]
for i in range(len(ar_regions_geo['features'])):
    ids.append(str(ar_regions_geo['features'][i]['properties']['density']))
    names.append(ar_regions_geo['features'][i]['properties']['name'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'provincia_id': ids, 'provincia': names, 'Total': np.random.randint(1500, 17000, len(ids))})

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(data_frame=df, 
                    geojson=ar_regions_geo, 
                    locations='provincia_id',
                    featureidkey='properties.density',  
                    color='Total', 
                    color_continuous_scale="burg", 
               )
fig.update_geos(showcountries=True, showcoastlines=True, showland=True, fitbounds="locations")
fig.update_layout(autosize=True, height=450, margin={"r":0,"t":20,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]